# how to run remote program on Powershell for long running program

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I need to run a long running program on a remote computer. Currently the exe runs as long as the PS session exists. if the session is removed the exe stops. How can i have the exe running even if the PS session is lost

```
$mmoVMTemplate = "Machine"


for($i=1;$i -le 80; $i++)
{


        $mmoVM = $mmoVMTemplate + $i


        .\InstallWinRMCertAzureVM.ps1 -SubscriptionName 'my subscription' -ServiceName $mmoVM -Name $mmoVM

        $secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
        $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('username', $secPassword)
        $uri = Get-AzureWinRMUri -ServiceName $mmoVM -Name $mmoVM

        $session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri $uri -Credential $credential

        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Set-Location "C:\MyProgram\"
        start-process -FilePath 'C:\MyProgram\TestTool.exe'}


        Disconnect-PSSession -Session $session

        Write-Host $mmoVM


}
```

Comment: You're not talking about the Disconnect-PSSession causing the program to exit, right?  You're talking about doing a Remove-PSSession (or the session times out) causing the program to exit.

Comment: currently i am using Disconnect-PSSession as a stop gap to make it work. Remove-PSSession is causing the program to exit

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter -Wait by `start-process -FilePath 'C:\MyProgram\TestTool.exe' -Wait`.
So the invoke comamnd waits until the TestTool.exe is finished.